# Is the sentence including "too far off" ambiguous without contexts?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, idioms

The sentence is "I shall be great deal too far off to trouble myself about you ".

The sentence has the context by which I can guess the meaning, but for studying English, I try to make a analysis.

The "off" is big trouble to me, I try to sort the syntax like "I shall be great deal about you, the deal is to trouble me, which is to be off, because of too far or too far away from me.

Is that right? Or is one of the possible meanings?

Is there standard explanation?

I edit the question above

The context is - Curiouser and curiouser!" cried Alice (she was so
much surprised that for the moment she quite forgot how to speak good English). "Now I'm opening out like the largest telescope that ever was! Good-by, feet! Oh, my poor little feet, I wonder who will put on your shoes and stockings for you now, dears? I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself about you.

I read again, the last sentence is whether like - I shall be about you, feet, the feet, when she had been her feet, there is a great deal, that's that she cut off or cut off in mind her feet, because she got trouble with the ability of run of feet?

Is that right?

Comment: Assuming this is not from an archaic source, I would say the sentence leaves me wondering how long the writer has been speaking English.

Comment: In particular, most native English speakers would say "**a** great deal".

Comment: Your first sentence is not idiomatic; your second makes no sense. It's hard to know what you are trying to say. Do you mean: *I shall be too far away to be bothered by you.* Your second sentence is garbled. You need to break it  into shorter sentences. You might say *I shall think a great deal about you* but you can't say *I shall be a great deal about you*. It's meaningless - or at least highly confusing.

Comment: @RonaldSole I edited the question, is there a time to take a look?

Comment: @user212295 The context is the clue. Alice is speaking to herself as she imagines that her body is being stretched out so that her feet fade into the distance. She feels that she is losing contact with her feet and wonders who will put shoes and stockings on the feet while the rest of her is elsewhere. She concludes that when she is separated from her feet, she will be too far off to worry about them.  The monologue is about a dream fantasy in which, as the writer confides, Alice uses quaint English.

Comment: There's no "deal" as in an agreement to do something here. *[a great deal](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/a-good-great-deal-of-something?q=a+great+deal)* is a set phrase, meaning: "a large amount or quantity of something".

Answer (score 1):

> I shall be a great deal too far off to trouble myself about you.

Translation, chunk by chunk:

> *[ I shall be ] [ a great deal ] [ too far off ] [ to trouble myself about you. ]*
>   = [ I will be ] [ very ] [ too far away from you ] [ to do anything about you. ]
>   ~ "I will be too very far away from you to do anything about you, my feet."

[A great deal](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/a-good-great-deal-of-something?q=a+great+deal) is a set phrase, meaning: "a large amount or quantity of something".

Why did Alice say so?

Because she was stretched out, like a telescope (see the image below), by the power of the cake after eating a cake in the previous chapter. (The sentence in question is from the first paragraph of chapter II of *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*.)

[image]
<sup>Source: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rgs/alice-II.html</sup>